# `npm install` times out on TFS 2015 build | dependencies are TFS-hosted Git repos

Tags: git, npm, tfs-2015, npm-install

In a TFS 2015 ("XPlat") build, the `npm install` step hangs until timeout. Timeouts of 10, 20, and 30 minutes have been tried.

`npm install` fetches local dependencies defined in the `package.json` files as commit-ish references, e.g.,

```
"ui-core": "git+http://tfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/etc/_git/ui-core"
```

I believe it is those dependencies that are causing the problem, because sometimes when I log into the build server (as the service account) and manually type `npm install` (in the directory of the build that timed out), the Git Credential Manager prompts me for authentication. However, the dependencies are not optional.

(No other errors are present in the event log, nor in the build log.)

We are using TFS-hosted Git, which requires domain-level authentication (Kerberos). This is handled in most of our environments by the [Git Credential Manager](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/wiki) (some people have suggested using `winstore` instead; please note that `git-credential-manager` is the replacement for `winstore` and `wincred` is not an option because TFS). However, authentication is also not optional (business requirement).

Also, note: We are running TFS 2015 Update 3, so the `npm install` issues solved by that update are probably not the cause (yes, all of the build agents have been updated). Edit: There was an answer here that suggested using SSH, which I fully support as a viable solution in general, but it was removed. I think that in our case the problem is that then all the developers would have to create and upload SSH publickey authentication tokens.

Has anyone else run into this issue? Is there an easy resolution I'm not finding? I'm not aware of any other credential managers that would do a better job, I don't know why the authentication gets dropped in the first place (or if there's a hack for that I'm missing), and short of keeping a copy of the repositories on another share that is manually updated (not preferable!) I can't see a good solution.

Comment: Can you try to configure your build agent to run with the same account that you use to install the GCM?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, because I installed the GCM as my domain user but the build agent cannot run with those permissions. I could try reinstalling the `choco` git package with the service account...

Comment: Does your build agent run as service or interactive mode?

Comment: There are three TFS2015 agents on this particular build server, and they all run as services. There are also two TFS2013 agents building legacy solutions.

Comment: Can you configure it to interactive mode to see if GCM credential dialog pops up during the build?

Comment: Great idea. I'll try it out and report the results.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/chaim1221/61d3bdd2874559a06673593bcc5ed043

Comment: So you can get it work now?

Comment: So here's a timeout:

https://gist.github.com/chaim1221/d52e6469f5c9ad77ed5bbef96f2f921b

Apparently something is cancelling the process.

Comment: ...nine minutes later, which is what the timeout is currently set to. So TFS is cancelling it. There's no output from `npm install` in those 9 minutes.

Comment: okay I think I fixed it by disabling the credential manager on the build server and instead enabling `git config credential.helper store`. The builds are working. If this keeps up I'll post that as an answer.

Comment: Glad to hear that. :)

Comment: Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

Basic (re)statement of the problem: TFS 2015 builds involving `npm install` don't finish, because the Git Credential Manager I've configured regularly asks the service user to re-authenticate in order to access the repositories specified by the [commit-ish](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#git-urls-as-dependencies).

Simplest solution: Remove the Git Credential Manager and use the `store` instead.

```
> git config --global --unset credential.manager
> git config credential.helper store
> git clone http://my-tfs-machine:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/TeamProject/_git/some-repo
Username for etc.: domain\user
Password for etc.: password
```

...and voila, that particular error is gone.

***Please note*** that this means the `password` for `user` is stored in plain text somewhere on the hard drive, and if that doesn't work as a solution in your domain, you'll have to find a different one.